# Installing zlib1g-dev in django app on Windows 10

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I am having issues installing zlib1g-dev (dependent for pillow). I am using a windows 10. I am getting this error.

```
project>pip install zlib1g-dev
Collecting zlib1g-dev
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zlib1g-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pypi package for zlib1g-dev.
Try `pip install zlib_wrapper`